# Sum of numbers in a column

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose you asked someone to write any two numbers one below the other, then write  the sum of these two numbers down , and keep writing the sum of the before two numbers up to $10$ lines. You could then "guess" the sum of the ten numbers by looking quickly at the column and multiplying the seventh number by $11$. Explain why this always happens

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DD8ntDpBm6Ok&ved=2ahUKEwjg7Pv-kMXlAhVkTt8KHeu0C14Qo7QBMAB6BAgAEAI&usg=AOvVaw04gCGHyl_yTmWLGqHSZsrz

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $a$ and $b$ be the two starting numbers

1. $a$
2. $b$
3. $a+b$
4. $a+2b$
5. $...$